# Forms en django

Tags: django, django-forms, djangorestframework

estoy empezando una pagina con django, pero me ocurrió lo siguiente a la hora de querer hacer un formulario.
Hice mi archivo forms.py y todo correcto, al momento de llamarlo mis campos se muestran, sin embargo ocurren las siguientes cosas.
1: No me deja guardar la información por que me dice "This field is required" en la parte de subir una imagen.
Este es mi view:

```
def agregarEscuela(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    escuelasForm = EscuelasForm(request.POST)
    if escuelasForm.is_valid():
        escuelasForm.save()
        return redirect('adminEscuelas')
else:
    escuelasForm = EscuelasForm()
return render(request, 'administracion/agregar_escuela.html',
              {'escuelasForm': escuelasForm})
```

Archivo html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Nueva persona</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Agregar Persona</h1>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        {{escuelasForm}}
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

imagen del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2: Para hacer una prueba quise hacer que ese campo no sea requerido (Este campo si acepta campos vacíos) pero no me refleja lo que pongo en widgets.
ejemplo:
Este es mi Forms:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput

from panel_administracion.models import Escuelas


class EscuelasForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Escuelas
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'email': TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'is_hidden': True,
                })}
```

Según aquí estoy diciendo que email no debería ser visible, sin embargo el campo aun es visible:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan echarme un cable, saludos cordiales!

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que en tus *models.py* tenes algo así:

```
class Escuela(models.Model):
    ...
    imagen = models.ImageField()
    ...
```

Si queres que la imagen no sea obligatoria tenés que agregar los atributos *null* y *blank* como verdaderos en el campo de la imagen:

```
class Escuela(models.Model):
    ...
    imagen = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```